# Why can't I access laravel relationship columns if I create new instance instead of using let's say "Article::all()"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm confused to why can't I access the relationship I setup if I use this code:

```php
$products = new Products();
```

If I use this, I can access my laravel relationship columns.

```php
$products = Products::all();
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are instantiating a regular php object, in the second example you are allowing laravel to instantiate the object. In such a case you are actually calling a named constructor that will utilize a `static boot()` method that is taking care of a lot of the heavy lifting under the hood.